# Timezones and email cron job: how to do it right?

Tags: php, timezone, message-queue

I've searched around in SO and elsewhere but have not found a direct answer to this, so at this point I believe it merits an entry here. Please advise if you think otherwise.

I am using Codeigniter 2.0.2, PHP 5.2.14, MySQL 5.0.77.

I am setting up a cron job that will run every 15 minutes. This cron job will run a model script that checks DB for events requiring an email alert. Events that return true are cue'd up for sending emails.

My issue is with the timezones of my users. My server is EST (UTC -5). If I have a user that registered as UTC +5, my script will send the email alert 10 hours earlier than expected.

To remedy this, I wanted to ask if this workflow is acceptable:

- user is UTC +5
- server is UTC -5
- scheduled event is 10PM (21:00) at user's local time
- subtract the timezone difference (21:00 - 10 = 11AM)
- send email out at 11AM

Some of the answers I found are here

[How to schedule emails to send out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571658/how-to-schedule-emails-to-send-out)

[Generating a schedule that works over different timezones and DSTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375289/generating-a-schedule-that-works-over-different-timezones-and-dsts)

but I wonder if someone could provide a better roadmap/schema to set up my script.

Any pointers are much appreciated, also re how to account for daylight saving time both local and from the user.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd save all the dates/times in UTC format and do the TZ adjustments at select time. This'd make the database more portable and easier to adjust for daylight savings and even moves if you switch providers and change the server's timezone.

Comment: thanks @marc - so i would clone the event time into another DB field, converting it to UTC and do all my calculations from the UTC time? just confirming to make sure i understood correctly.

Comment: By the way, 10pm = 22.00

Answer (score 2):

As suggested already I would normalise all dates being written into your database into UTC and then you can read them out of there easily, converting back as you read them if necessary.

The [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function will let you easily perform these conversions. eg.

```
CONVERT_TZ('2011-05-11 15:23:00','GMT','Europe/London');
```

Comment: thanks @james - could your line of code replace the function provided by @jimmy above? ie, is your suggestion all i'd need to resolve this issue (besides normalizing)?

Comment: @torr Yes, I believe the code above performs the same time of conversion as suggested by Jimmy. The difference is that my suggestion works in the MySQL database and his in PHP. You could use `CONVERT_TZ()` for normalising too, just cast from the local timezone to GMT/UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to convert timezones:

```
function switch_timezone($format, $time = null, 
    $to = "America/Los_Angeles", $from = "America/Los_Angeles")
{
    if ($time == null) $time = time();

    $from_tz = new DateTimeZone($from);
    $to_tz = new DateTimeZone($to);

    if (is_int($time)) $time = '@' . $time;

    $dt = date_create($time, $from_tz);

    if ($dt)
    {
        $dt->setTimezone($to_tz);
        return $dt->format($format);
    }

    return date($format, $time);
}
```

Seems like you should be able to use it to convert your current time into the right database time for `SELECT`s and vice versa.

Comment: thanks @jimmy - do i need to add `date('I',$timestamp)` to check for DST or does the `DateTimeZone` class take care of this?

Comment: The `DateTimeZone` class takes care of it. You just tell it what time zone you're in, it knows how to deal with it.

Comment: that's pretty sweet, I'll try your script and post back with results - thanks again

Comment: i ran a test and when converting from `NY` to `LA` time, it gives me `LA` time with a -1 hour error (currently they are running on `PDT` -- do you get the same result?

Comment: It works for me - are you using `America/New_York` and `America/Los_Angeles`?